# Mapping Drive SharePoint 2013 not working in windows 7

Tags: 2013, public-website, mapped-folder

I am new in SharePoint and learning it. In the beginning I tried to manage mapping drive successfully but after couple of days it's no longer working. I can log in to the Windows server 2008 remotely but the mapping for the server

```
\\server_name\sites\my_site\_catalogs\masterpage\ no longer works.
```

It gives me the following error always "The network path was not found"

Although i can browse it through browser but of course can't edit any files.

```
http://win-lcrsm0ef404/sites/my_site/_catalogs/masterpage
```

Tried to Google it and did so many searching but no luck.

Wish someone can help me figure out how to access those master page files in the server or where can I find it in c:/ drive as I am very new to share point development from PHP/MySQL background.

Answer (score 1):

I would install and use [SharePoint Designer 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491) if you are trying to edit masterpages. It gives you a markup editor similar to visual studios and it provides you with the tools you need in order to customize, manage, and structure SharePoint sites, as well as give you access to the files on virtual folders.

Alternatively, if you want to use WEBDAV in order to access these pages directly, try using the FQDN, and make sure the WebClient service is started both on the client machine and on the server. There's also a hotfix for this if you are using IE10: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846960

Comment: Thanks for the info. Anyhow I solved it. It seems like you have to restart the server and login from the server to make this drive mapping work. Still don't know why it's happening. But this is the workaround I got so far.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the "Web Client" service is running on your windows 7 system